# Logstash Date filter on special date format

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Im trying to store old log files in elastic and im using logstash for that.

time stamps in the logs are of the following format:

```
13 AUG 2015 | 07:04:35 | .......
```

1st problem was the fact the month is in upper case so i copied the "MONTH" pattern as it appears in the grok-patterns and upper-cased all of it:

original MONTH:

```
MONTH \b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b
```

my upper-case "MONTHCAP":

```
MONTHCAP \b(?:JAN(?:UARY)?|FEB(?:RUARY)?|MAR(?:CH)?|APR(?:IL)?|MAY|JUN(?:E)?|JUL(?:Y)?|AUG(?:UST)?|SEP(?:TEMBER)?|OCT(?:OBER)?|NOV(?:EMBER)?|DEC(?:EMBER)?)\b
```

next thing i try to do is use the date filter so elastic uses the timestamp from the log as @timestamp filed and NOT the time of the line being stored in elastic:

```
date{
                match => ["MONTHDAY","dd","MONTHCAP","MMM","YEAR","yyyy","TIME","HH:mm:ss"]
    }
```

The problem is that i get the following error trying to store the data:

```
Error: Cannot register filter date plugin. The error reported is:
Illegal pattern component: O for pattern 'MONTHCAP'
```

additional information:
this is the grok filter i use to parse the log lines:

```
%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTHCAP} %{YEAR} \| %{TIME} \|
```

any idea why i keep getting this error when thr pattern i use is 'MMM' ?
THanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation the match is only for one field :

```
match => [ "logdate", "MMM dd YYY HH:mm:ss",
      "MMM  d YYY HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601" ]
```

It takes the first solution which matchs with logdate field.

You need to construct a field which is your date and after you can do your date filter.

```
 match => [logdate, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss]
```

Comment: Thanks, i get it. But how do i put all the separate time stamp fields into one ?

Comment: filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "foo_%{somefield}" => "Hello world, from %{host}" }
  }
}

Comment: THanks. now that i got it working and i added all fields to create one as you suggested   'add_field => { "logTimeStamp" => "%{day} %{month} %{year} %{time}" }' but for some reason the date filter still doesn't work :(             date{ match =>["logTimeStamp","dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss" ]  }. could it be the fact that the month are is upper case letters??  i.e  JAN,FEB etc. and the MMM represents Jan,Feb,... etc?